# Use Sanitize::clean without Database connection at CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am working over Oracle DataBase and CakePHP 2.3.
As CakePHP doesn't support Oracle (there are no drivers for it), I am using Oracle procedures or php OCI8 functions in my models.

As a result of it, I am working with CakePHP without any effective database link in the eyes of CakePHP framework.

I am trying to use the `Sanitize::clean` method in order to clean a comment before saving it in the database and I am having troubles as it seems to look in the database for its task.

This is the resulting error:

> Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

And this is how I try to sanitize it:

```
$comment = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data['comment']);
```

It works perfectly well if i just do this:

```
$comment = $this->request->data['comment'];
```

Is it possible somehow to use `Sanitize::clean` without any configured database at CakePHP 2.3?

Thanks

Comment: What error(s) are you getting when you try to use it?  Also please post your actual code when using it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Although my code is not too relevant :)

Comment: It shows the same error.

Comment: What exactly do mean by "clean a comment"? Are you trying to use `Sanitize::clean` for escaping, ie for preventing SQL injections?

Comment: Or to prevent HTML or Javascript injections.

Comment: You should only use it for the or part, in order to prevent SQL injections it is highly recommended to use the DB drivers own mechanisms! For OCI8 see [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Comment: Yeah, I am using them and the bind params. I just want to avoid other type of attacks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Sanitize::clean() expects 2 arguments, by default when you do not give a second argument CakePHP uses its default values and tries to connect to a DB with the 'default' connection. After a quick glance at the Sanitize Class in the library, it appears that it is the 'escape' option that requires a DB connection. It is called by default to make a string SQL-safe.

So in your case, as you don't need a SQL connection, this request should do the trick:

`$comment = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data['comment'], array('escape' => false);`

[Check the CookBook for more information on the Sanitize class.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html)